# platform exception in stripe_flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

Describe the bug
im facing the issue after the server to getting the clientsecret successfully after that i'm setup the stripe code then i click to hit the request of stripe payment getting I'm showing the platform exception i'm already update mainactivity.kt file fluttteractvity to fragment
below im paste the my issue which one showing into log please check and help me how to fix

PlatformException(flutter_stripe initialization failed, The plugin failed to initialize: Your theme isn't set to use Theme.AppCompat or Theme.MaterialComponents. Please check the README: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#android, null, null)

Answer (score 1):

I think You are using

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

And it should be:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

or just, copy and paste all the file in style.xml

[https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml](https://Copy%20This)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue, and I initially was a bit confused by the previous two answers. After studying it and testing more, I think they're both correct. In my project I changed from NoTitleBar to ToActionBar (as described in Shailandra's answer) AND I also changed the windowBackground to ?android:colorBackground (as described in Asif's answer). As Asif mentioned, there are also two separate styles.xml files to change, in the values folder and one in the values-night folder.

values/styles.xml should be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And values-night/styles.xml should be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is on -->
    <!-- TODO document the necessary change -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also one small clarification, the title on the original question mentions stripe_flutter which is deprecated, but the issue is with flutter_stripe.

Hope this is helpful to anyone else who experiences this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your both style file.

1. /android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
   2./android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml

@drawable/launch_background
        true
    
    
    
        ?android:colorBackground